# Send an email with Gmail, from Python script

Tags: python, email, gmail

I'm trying to send an email from a python script bue I get this error. I'm using a virtual server and I don't have control over the network now.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendemail.py", line 10, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 566, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

The script in question, is this:

```
import smtplib
fromaddr = 'xpto@xpto.com'
toaddrs  = 'xxx@xxx.com'

msg = 'my message'

username = 'xpto@xpto.com'
password = 'password'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: I suggest you check out your network,and try your code on another computer.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the repply, I think that the problem is on my firewall.

Comment: Comment if your code ran successfully

Comment: It did on my own machine, but not on the server.